# My word filter stops all other commands from working (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a word filter, it works perfectly fine but when I then tried to use a command I had trouble using it, as in the commands for my bot (used in cogs) aren't working if the filter is being used (in the main file)
the command is this.

```
#Censor/Filter
with open("badwords.txt") as file: # badwords.txt contains one phrase per line
    bad_words = [bad_word.strip().lower() for bad_word in file.readlines()] # Reading

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if any(bad_word in message.content.lower() for bad_word in bad_words):
        channel = bot.get_channel(859495659639668757)
        await channel.send("{}, your message has been censored.".format(message.author.mention))
        await message.delete()
```

Is there anything I can do to make the commands work?

Adding
`await bot.process_commands(message)` onto the end of the event will allow the command to function if it gets deleted.

Comment: It partially helped as in the now the command will work but it has to be deleted to actually work.

Comment: Idents @Someonelookinforhelp